# How to get response of meeting invitation email in php

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am sending calendar meeting invitation to user's email.

When receiver accepts invitation then it appears in receivers calendar but I am not able to get response.

Is there any way that I can get response and use it in my website?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: added PHP tag and remove PHP from question

Comment: In calendar UI(from which calendar you are creating event) in the calendar settings,click on "edit notifications", select on "event responses". This will give notification when invitee accepts the invitation

Comment: I am sending meeting invitation mail in PHP. I am not sending request from any calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Service Account is the perfect solution in this case. In this, users do not need any API detail instead site owner needs API detail. Read Google service account documentation and you will find solution of your problem.